# How to get host list by host groupid in zabbix?

Tags: zabbix, json-rpc

I am trying host.get API to get all host of an host groupid. I am using the jsonrpc as below.

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "host.get",
    "params": {
        "output": ["host"],
        "groupids": ["10"]
    },
    "auth": "a5eb4e6c2c5b4c0696056c2039dec657",
    "id": 1
}
```

In the database have 13 host in the host groupid=10. However, the API return only one host with the hostid is biggest in 13 host in groupid=10.
I don't know why it doesn't return the host list.

Please help me.
Thank you so much,
BienHV

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that the jsonrpc data is correct. Your problem is somewhere else: check user permissions, and the host group content.